# Alternative name for overhead line, typically for data link between buildings

Tags: terminology

What is the term I should use to describe an overhead cable link that typically connects two buildings across a gap, eg a road?

For the life of me, I can't remember the word I'm looking for.  I think it may sound like the words *stanchion* or *catamaran*, but I can't place the actual word I have heard used to describe this type of link.

Apologies if this question is better suited to another SE site.

Comment: You may be thinking of "catenary", but that describes the shape of a cable suspended at two points, not the use of the cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not entirely correct, the term "catenary" is often used in connection with this sort of installation - probably more for the sake of having *something* to call it other than just "overhead wire". The name "catenary" actually comes from the mathematical equation that describes the curve formed by a chain or cable suspended by its two ends in a gravitational field and is derived from the hyperbolic cosine function (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Geometrical_properties) for a longer description that is somewhat off-topic for this site). For engineering purposes, it allows you to calculate the load on the fixings at the two ends and the expected "droop" in the cable in between.

Sometimes, the use is more specific, such as this paragraph from a [press release issued by Network Rail in the UK](https://www.networkrail.co.uk/running-the-railway/our-routes/lne-and-em/midland-main-line-improvement-programme/):

> Generally, most types of railway overhead line equipment have overhead
>   conductors with a copper contact wire suspended from a catenary wire
>   by 'droppers' or 'drop wires.'

But the term is often applied to anything strung between points such as catenary bridges or walkways.

Comment: +1 I'd add catenary is actually related to how a cable or chain will naturally form a parabola when suspended from the ends. The mechanical forces and tensions involved are mathematically defined so you can tell how strong a cable needs to be and how much tension (droop) should be applied to it to span a particular distance under a variety of wind and ice loads.

Comment: Will do, @Trevor - but it's not a parabola!

Comment: Riight... hyperbolic cosine...